# Java BigDecimal without E

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a BigDecimal variable

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("5521.0000000001");
```

Formula:

```
x = x.add(new BigDecimal("-1")
      .multiply(x.divideToIntegralValue(new BigDecimal("1.0"))));
```

I want to remove the integer part, to get the value `x = ("0.0000000001")`, but my new value is 1E-10 and not the 0.0000000001.

Comment: 1e-10 is 0.0000000001, so it's just a matter of presentation.

Comment: Try [toPlainString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()).

Answer (score 23):

To get a `String` representation of the `BigDecimal` without the exponent part, you can use
[`BigDecimal.toPlainString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29). In your example:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("5521.0000000001");
x = x.add(new BigDecimal("-1").
              multiply(x.divideToIntegralValue(new BigDecimal("1.0"))));
System.out.println(x.toPlainString());
```

prints

```
0.0000000001
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using BigDecimal.toPlainString() to get value as plain string as you require.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using BigDecimal isn't really helping you.

```
double d = 5521.0000000001;
double f = d - (long) d;
System.out.printf("%.10f%n", f);
```

prints

```
0.0000000001
```

but the value `5521.0000000001` is only an approximate representation.

The actual representation is

```
double d = 5521.0000000001;
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d));
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(d).subtract(new BigDecimal((long) d));
System.out.println(db);
```

prints

```
5521.000000000100044417195022106170654296875
1.00044417195022106170654296875E-10
```

I suspect whatever you are trying to is not meaningful as you appear to be trying to obtain a value which is not what you think it is.

Comment: so when System.out.println(bd);, I assume that's printing the .toString() representation, not .toPlainString()

Comment: @AlexMills println always calls the toString () even for String I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this at your BigDecimal object and not convert it into a String with a formatter you can do it on Java 8 with 2 steps:

1. stripTrailingZeros()
2. if scale < 0 setScale to 0 if don't like esponential/scientific
   notation

You can try this snippet to better understand the behaviour

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("50"));
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
if (bigDecimal.scale()<0)
bigDecimal= bigDecimal.setScale(0);
System.out.println(bigDecimal);//50
bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("50.20"));
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
if (bigDecimal.scale()<0)
bigDecimal= bigDecimal.setScale(0);
System.out.println(bigDecimal);//50.2
bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("50"));
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(bigDecimal);//5E+1
bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("50.20"));
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros();
System.out.println(bigDecimal);//50.2
```